# How do I reset mocked values in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am trying my hand jest and writing unit tests.
I have written unit tests for couple of functions. These functions use an object of constants imported from a different file. So I have mocked these constants.

```
describe('testing helpers', () => {

    beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules());

    describe('reset board', () => {
        // first test using original constant values
        test('with default constants', () => {
            const game = {
                board: [
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                ],
                count: 0
            };

            const helper = require('./helper');
            expect(helper.resetBoard()).toEqual(game);
        });

        // second test using mocked constant values
        test('reset board', () => {
            const game = {
                board: [
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                ],
                count: 0
            };  

            jest.mock("./constants", () => ({ ROWS: 4, COLUMNS: 5 }));

            const helper = require('./helper');
            expect(helper.resetBoard()).toEqual(game);
        });
    });

    describe('make move', () => {
        // third test with original constant values
        test('player 1 move', () => {

            const testBoard = [
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                ];
            const testTurn = 'YELLOW';
            const testColumn = 0;

            const expectedBoard = [
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                ];

            const helper = require('./helper');
            helper.makeMove(testBoard, testTurn, testColumn);
            expect(testBoard).toEqual(expectedBoard);
        });
    });
});
```

But when the third test which is in the second describe block is running it is picking up the mocked values instead of the original values. I thought this `beforeEach(() => jest.resetModules());` would reset the mocked values but it is not working.
Please help with this.
Any other tips for improving on the tests will be appreciated.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, here you go https://repl.it/repls/AdmirableQueasyFlashdrives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jest.resetModules` only resets module cache and allows to reimport modules, it doesn't affect module mocks in effect:

> Resets the module registry - the cache of all required modules. This is useful to isolate modules where local state might conflict between tests.

In order for module mock to be discarded, `jest.unmock` or `jest.dontMock` needs to be used. If a default behaviour for these tests is unmocked `constants`, this can be:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.unmock("./constants");
  jest.resetModules();
});
```

In this scenario it's easier to import original implementation at top level and use it in tests that need it:

```
const helper = require('./helper');
...
```

And `require` a mock only in tests that need mocked implementation of `helper` or modules that it depends on (`constants`). `beforeEach` with `jest.resetModules` and `jest.unmock` is still desirable in order for these tests to not cross-contaminate each other, tests that use top-level `helper` won't be affected by it.

Comment: Using `restoreAllMocks`, `clearAllMocks`, and `resetModules` was not enough for me so I had to resort to `unmock` and `deepUnmock`. Is there any `unmockAll` or `deepUnmockAll`? Would be nice so that I don't have to write each specific one everytime.

Answer (score -1):

This could work out.

```js
describe('testing helpers', () => {
    beforeEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());
    ....
})
```

if use `jest + @testing-library/react`

```js
import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react'

beforeEach(cleanup)
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything. A hierarchy of describe affects which before* and after* tests affect tests. Since all tests share a common describe block, beforeEach affects all of them.

Comment: It's only for Jest spies, not module mocks. `jest.resetModules()` is called for all tests in the OP, there should be no problem with it. I'm quite sure the problem is what I posted.